# Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user and the user does exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory

I put a user into an AD group, and after that, i used the below syntax to find if he has been put:

```
xp_logininfo 'domain\group_name', 'members'
```

and find the user `domain\username` is listed.

And then, I checked the user's permission path, using the following statements:

```
xp_logininfo 'domain\user_name', 'all'
 
execute as user = 'domain\user_name'
```

None of them worked, and all showing the error message as:

```
Msg 15404, Level 16, State 19, Line 12
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\user_name', error code 0x5.
```

So what happens when query this user?

Comment: Do you have sysadmin role membership for your own account when executing xp_logininfo?

Comment: [*"Permissions: Requires membership in the `sysadmin` fixed server role or membership in the `public` fixed database role in the `master` database with `EXECUTE` permission granted."*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-logininfo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions)

Answer (score 0):

The error code 0x5 indicates access denied. Here are some troubleshooting methods.

•   Check the user indeed exists in the AD group.

•   Check if the service account is not disabled.

•   Check if the user has dataread permissions.